# Treeview of Controls with collapse/expand

Tags: c#, .net, windows, treeview

Platform: C# windows.
.Net Framework 3.5, 4.0.
I have some set of controls which I want to display as treeview. I have added the set of controls to treeview as follows:

```
Control control;

.................
.................   

Treeview1.Controls.Add(control);
```

It shows me the control in treeview like panel. It is not showing any hierarchy or plus/minus sign. So I am unable to collapse/expand tree node.
Please would you suggest me a way to solve it.

Comment: TreeView is designed to show `Node`s as hierarchical manner not the `Control`s

Comment: Post a Screenshot of what you need. I'm pretty sure you can't do what you want in winforms.

Comment: Sorry, I am having reputation less than 10 so I am unable to post any image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Banketeshvar you can use Flowlayout panel or WPF Expander.

WPF Expander Code is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfExpander.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3,3,3,3">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="85" />
        <RowDefinition Height="220" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Expander Grid.Row="1" Header="expander1" Name="expander1" IsExpanded="False">            
            <ListBox>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 1"/>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 2"/>
            </ListBox>           

  </Expander>
  <Expander Grid.Row="2" Header="expander2" Name="expander2" IsExpanded="False">
   <ListBox>
       <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 1"/>
       <ListBoxItem Content="Unit 2"/>
   </ListBox>
  </Expander>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and FlowLayout Panel code is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool _open;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.ClientSize = new Size(this.panel1.ClientSize.Width,0);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_open)
        {
            this.flowLayoutPanel1.ClientSize = new Size(this.panel1.ClientSize.Width,0);
            //this.ClientSize = new Size(this.panel1.ClientSize.Width, this.panel1.ClientSize.Height);                
            this.button1.Text = "+";
        }
        else
        {
            //this.ClientSize = new Size(this.panel1.ClientSize.Width, this.panel1.ClientSize.Height + this.flowLayoutPanel1.PreferredSize.Height);
             this.flowLayoutPanel1.ClientSize= new Size(this.panel1.ClientSize.Width, this.panel1.ClientSize.Height + this.flowLayoutPanel1.PreferredSize.Height);
            this.button1.Text = "-";
        }

        this._open = !this._open;
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn1=new Button();
        btn1.Text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Height += 100;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn1);

    }
  }
}



partial class Form1
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.flowLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
        this.button5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 30);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(127, 9);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label1.Text = "label1";
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 4);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // flowLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SandyBrown;
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 36);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Name = "flowLayoutPanel1";
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(553, 289);
        this.flowLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // button5
        // 
        this.button5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(38, 389);
        this.button5.Name = "button5";
        this.button5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button5.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button5.Text = "Add Buttons";
        this.button5.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button5.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button5_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(840, 453);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button5);
        this.Controls.Add(this.flowLayoutPanel1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel flowLayoutPanel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button5;
}
```

If you are not adding the control at run time then you can use simple Panel Control instead of FlowLayoutPanelControl.

You can also use normal Panel Control for dynamic controls but FlowLayoutPanel provides some add-on properties.